# EWS: How to convert Public Folder MAPI EntryID to EWS FolderID

Tags: exchangewebservices

My code works perfect if folders are private
For example if the folder belong to **private message store** tcFolderId="00000000C29BEF8308F4AD4188BDF6CB1517D65401008AC18FCDFD1EF64FBB5D946C26787598000000BC70750000"

```
Public Function mmks_ConvertMAPIFolderIdToEWSFolderId(tcFolderId As String, tcMailBox As String) As String
    Dim loHexEntryID As New AlternateId(IdFormat.HexEntryId, tcFolderId, tcMailBox)
    Dim loEntryId As AlternateId = _pmks_exchangeService.ConvertId(loHexEntryID, IdFormat.EntryId)
    Return CType(_pmks_exchangeService.ConvertId(loEntryId, IdFormat.EwsId), AlternateId).UniqueId
End Function
```

But for **public message store** this code does not work.
When Public FolderId = "000000001A447390AA6611CD9BC800AA002FC45A0300D32A8E9A328D734A98B8E1E7D3C591F5012EE3EFFFB60000"
After conversion this code returns
"AAMkADkwZTlhMjA2LWQ1NTUtNDNkOS04N2M3LWYyZmFkZDFjMjlmNgAuAAAAAAAaRHOQqmYRzZvIAKoAL8RaAwDTKo6aMo1zSpi44efTxZH1AS7j7/+2AAA="

But this is wrong.
Because I rescan PublicFoldersRoot using FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot) and this folder has UniqueId = "AQEuAAADGkRzkKpmEc2byACqAC/EWgMA0yqOmjKNc0qYuOHn08WR9QEu4+//tgAAAA=="

The questio is:
How to convert Public message store folder EntryID into EWS FolderId?

Comment: Also keep in mind that multiple ids can refer to the same object, you should never compare them directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the AlternatePublicFolderId Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/alternatepublicfolderid for public Folders eg

```
Public Function mmks_ConvertMAPIFolderIdToEWSFolderId(tcFolderId As String, tcMailBox As String) As String
    Dim loHexEntryID As New AlternatePublicFolderId (IdFormat.HexEntryId, tcFolderId, tcMailBox)
    Dim loEntryId As AlternatePublicFolderId = _pmks_exchangeService.ConvertId(loHexEntryID, IdFormat.EntryId)
Return CType(_pmks_exchangeService.ConvertId(loEntryId, IdFormat.EwsId), AlternatePublicFolderId).UniqueId
```

End Function

Comment: Ths solution was helpfull. Thank you very much!